# Translating アンニュイに言われても

Tags: manga, phrases

I have difficulty translating the phrase アンニュイに言われても: it seems to me that breaking them into pieces that I can use dictionary feels off. Google translate often does better when it is given a full sentence, and I think it is almost correct, but I would like to see if there is better way to do this.

The conversation started off like this:

```
A:　B,　アイス食べたくない？
B:　…そんなアンニュイに言われても…
A:  え？食べたくない？
B:　だから！！
A:  私は食べたいよ？
B:　食べればいいじゃない！
A:  でも冷凍庫にアイスないもん
B:　じゃあ、我慢しよーよ…
```

The closest I could find is "even if you say so", which I used Google translate plus personal interpretation. But if I break it into pieces, the first phrase means "ennui" which is closer to boredom (which matches the context, when A said she suggested she wants ice cream out of a sudden), but it does not fit the sentence literally.

The source is from a manga I read, for reference it's chapter 59 of 兄の嫁と暮らしています。

**EDIT:** I seemed to have missed に in the middle of the phrase, which is now corrected.

Comment: It looks like we're possibly lacking context from before A suggests getting ice cream. Please provide source if you can and what you have found アンニュイ to mean.

Comment: It looks like 'ennui', but I can't possibly understand what that word would be doing here.

Comment: @BJCUAI I have added some details. Unfortunately, from the source, the conversation literally started that way, which is not really out of context in my opinion.

Comment: 「アンニュイ"に"言われても」なら分かります（単に「けだるく」とか「興味なさそうに」みたいな意味です）が、本当に「アンニュイ言われても」ですか？

Comment: @Everiana That manga seems to be listed as diary entries, rather than chapters, with 'Diary.57' being the latest release. Do you have an advance copy or am I missing something?

Comment: @BJCUAI https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B07P7PQP5Q/ これですね

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original text is アンニュイ**に**言われても. It's "say it in an アンニュイ way" rather than "say アンニュイ".

[image: image clip]

アンニュイに (from French *ennui*) in this context means "lacking energy", "without passion", "listlessly", "as if you were uninterested/bored", "drowsily", etc.

At least in Japanese, アンニュイ sometimes has a positive connotation. アンニュイな魅力を持つ人 or アンニュイな雰囲気の人 can refer to an attractive person because of their coolness or expressionlessness. See [this article](https://ranking-best.net/79) for example.

Comment: That clears it up, thanks. Sorry for the typo :O